# error with split: split is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code that performs an ajax request on button click.

```
$('#allinea').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db_align.php",
        data: {password:password},
        complete: function(data){ 
            data1=data.split("|");
            if(data1[0]=="Successo"){ 
                $("#per_all").fadeTo(200,0.1,
                function(){
                    $(this).find('img').attr("src",'../images/ok.png');
                    $(this).find('.right').html(data1[1]).promise().done(function(){
                        $(this).fadeTo(900,1);
                    });
                });
            }else if(data1[0]=="Errore"){
                $("#per_all").fadeTo(200,0.1,
                function(){
                    $(this).find('img').attr("src",'../images/alert.png');
                    $(this).find('.right').html(data1[1]).promise().done(function(){
                        $(this).fadeTo(900,1);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }); //chiudo $.ajax
});
```

The php page returns "Successo|Allineamento riuscito" and I see it correctly in firebug but the js returns an error:

> Type error: data.split is not a function
>
> data1=data.split("|");

I use this code everywhere in my app without any inconvenient. What am I doing wrong this time?

For what I see btw this is not an array so this should work without any inconvenient!

Comment: If you want jQuery to return JSON all the time force it using `dataType: json` , for plain text `dataType : text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exo's answer is perfect. It will allow you to edit the raw text.

If you know the type of data returning, you can (must) set it explicitly. jQuery will then programmatically convert `data` for you in the correct format.

`dataType: json` for JSON, 
`dataType: text` for plain text

More can be found in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

> You should update your `complete` method to `done` for success condition and `fail` for when the request fails.
>
> `complete` is deprecated as of *version 1.8*, it's replaced with `always`, which returns a `data` or `jqXHR` object. When success `complete` will return a `data` object according to the functionality of `done`.

Comment: Got the point but my doubt remains. I copy pasted this code from one of the many Ajax call I have built in my app. I always return raw text from php and the js is working properly. I will have a look at the point about complete. Guess i will have a bit of work to update my code :)

Comment: Normally jQuery would guess the data-type and return the object it thinks it is. Here it has no clue I guess.

Comment: found out what is the reason of this failure. If input data are text (usually I serialize data form) jQuery will assume that also output data are text (as I normally putput). This time I input a json array and output some text. Thanks again for the hint

Answer (score 5):

jQuery will return a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) here, which means that instead of accessing `data` directly, you will probably need to do `data.responseText`.

Comment: In 99 out of 100 cases data is ok. This is the only case where is not working. Will have a look to your answer anyway!